# Desplegar campos dinámicamente en HTML

Tags: javascript

Tengo este archivo JSON:

```
{nombre_form: "Oscar Francisco Vargas Tudela", nombre_nit_form: "Oscar Vargas Tudela", nits_form: "55555555555", nits: Array(3)}
nits: Array(3)
0: {nit: "1111111111111"}
1: {nit: "22222222222222"}
2: {nit: "69999999"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
nits_form: "55555555555"
nombre_form: "Oscar Francisco Vargas Tudela"
nombre_nit_form: "Oscar Vargas Tudela"
```

Como pueden ver, tengo en la variable `nits` un diccionario con 3 elementos.

Esos datos de cada `nit` quisiera poder desplegarlos aquí:

```
<div class="wrap-input100">
<input type="button" id="popupbutton" onclick="popup()"/>
<ul id="checkBundle">
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test4</label>
</ul>
</div>
```

Y si no, estaría abierto a considerar otras alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es iterar por cada elemento con [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y crear los elementos `<label>` e `<input>` a demanda:

```js
/* Datos reproducidos de la pregunta */
let datos = {
  nombre_form: "Oscar Francisco Vargas Tudela",
  nombre_nit_form: "Oscar Vargas Tudela",
  nits_form: "55555555555",
  nits: [
    { nit: "1111111111111" },
    { nit: "22222222222222" },
    { nit: "69999999" },
  ],
};

function rellenar_checkbox(id, datos) {
  let elem = document.getElementById(id);
  /* Primero borramos el contenido */
  while (elem.firstChild) {
    elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
  }
  /* Luego agregamos un elemento por cada valor de los datos */
  datos.forEach(dato => {
    /* Creamos los elementos HTML */
    let label = document.createElement("label");
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    /* Configuramos el tipo del input */
    input.type = "checkbox";
    /* Introducimos el texto del label y el valor del input*/
    label.innerText = dato.nit;
    input.value = dato.nit;
    /* Introducimos el input antes del texto */
    label.prepend(input);
    /* Lo agregamos al documento HTML */
    elem.appendChild(label);
  });
}

/* Llamamos a la función creada */
rellenar_checkbox("checkBundle", datos.nits);
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul id="checkBundle">
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />test4</label>
</ul>
```

El HTML generado será:

```
<ul id="checkBundle">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1111111111111">1111111111111</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="22222222222222">22222222222222</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="69999999">69999999</label>
</ul>
```